# Laravel appended attribute returns null when model is initiated through dependecy injection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, append, accessor, laravel-permission

I have an appended attribute that works when I do `Model::first()->appended_attribute`, but when get the model object instantiated through laravel's route dependency injection like below :

```php
public function update(UserRequest $request, User $user)
{
 $user->appended_attribute; // returns null       

}
```

When I access it it returns `null`, Though when I do `$user->toArray()` the appended attributes does exist but with a value of null.
And if I do this :

```php
public function update(UserRequest $request, User $user)
{
 User::find($user->id)->appended_attribute; // returns it's correct value

}
```

It does work.

The append attribute method :

```php
public function getCurrentRoleAttribute()
{
  return $this->roles->first();
}
```

**Is there anything I'm missing ?**

Comment: It is really weird, butbplease, share the code related to the appended attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer:

It's a miss use of spatie's permissions package.

#### Long answer:

Thanks to @IGP 's answer for giving me a hint about the missing relation load, I found out that it's not that it's missing, it's actually the opposite !!.
After removing this line from the user model it worked :

```
protected $with = ['roles'];
```

It was because I'm using spatie's permissions package which uses the team_id provided after the user's login to load the user's `roles` relation (in that team). Now me setting the relation to be eagerly loaded with the `$with` property is basically saying load the relation before setting the team_id !!, **That's why it was returning null**.

**SORRY FOR NOT PROVIDING MORE INFO ABOUT THE ISSUE (:'**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a relationship that might not be loaded? Try adding this to your accessor.

```php
public function getCurrentRoleAttribute()
{
    $this->loadMissing('roles');

    return $this->roles->first();
}
```